# How do I update a qty field from adding and subtracting fields with timestamps?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE cartons_current (
    part_no varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    qty INT(8) NOT NULL,
    qty_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE cartons_added
    part_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    add_qty INT(8) NOT NULL,
    add_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE cartons_pulled (
    part_no VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    pull_qty INT(8) NOT NULL,
    pull_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

I first create a new record in `cartons_current` inserting values in the "part_no" and "qty" columns.

Next, I later need to add or pull (subtract) from "qty" using two other columns for adding and pulling.

How do I make "qty" show the latest result from `cartons_added` and `cartons_pulled`?

I also need to timestamp each new, add and pull.

Comment: As you have explained them above, these should not be three different tables. Rather one table with 4 columns `part_no, qty, add_qty, pull_qty`

Comment: Do you have to use this table structure?  Seems very repetitive.  CARTONS_CURRENT seems to be your inventory table and the other two are being used to record using inventory and stocking inventory.  What I would suggest is having one table to store the current carton inventory and another table to record transactions for the inventory.  You could add a timestamp as well to the transaction table.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` statements are better than the results of `DESCRIBE` statements since they are [sample code](http://sscce/) that can be tested directly.

Comment: @Erik If I wasn't clear below, if you need timestamps and multiple add/pull per part, then you really do need three tables. I reformatted your structure above.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has `trigger` written all over it:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_cartons_added_each AFTER UPDATE ON cartons_added 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE cartons_current cc SET cc.qty = cc.qty + NEW.qty_added - OLD.qty_added;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

If you follow @Michael's advice and put all data in one table, you can let MySQL do the calculation for the current_qty:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_cartons_each BEFORE UPDATE ON cartons 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.current_qty = old.current_qty 
                      + (new.qty_added - old.qty_added)
                      - (new.qty_pulled - old.qty_pulled);
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

In a BEFORE UPDATE trigger you can change the values, so you can do your timestamp magic in those, you you store the last change.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ai_cartons_each BEFORE UPDATE ON cartons 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.qty_added <> old.qty_added THEN 
    SET new.added_timestamp = NOW();
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is this on the client side or server side?

Comment: @Erik, TRIGGERS are always server side.

Answer (score 0):

These should all be in one table `cartons`. Then to query your current quantity, simply do:

```
SELECT
  part_no,
  -- To keep track of your initial quantity
  qty AS original_qty,
  add_qty,
  pull_qty,
  -- Arithmetic to calculate the current actual quantity
  qty + add_qty - pull_qty AS new_qty
FROM cartons
```

Comment: Thanks.  But I also wanted to capture the timestamp for each update.  I thought I needed a separate table for each? I simplified this for the example.

Comment: @Erik Edit and add the timestamp cols to your question. I'll delete this in a while.

Comment: Don't delete this..  hold on to it.. It will help.

Comment: Michael, I updated the question and consolidated the tables together.  Can you still help me?

Comment: I think you'll need to use @Johan 's trigger solution.