# mySQL - updating a qty field from adding and subtracting fields and capture timestamps? How?

Tags: mysql

I have one table:

I first create a new record in CARTONS_CURRENT inserting values to "part_no" and "qty".

Next, I later need to add or pull (subtract) from "qty" using two other columns for adding and pulling.

How do I make "qty" show the latest result from CARTONS_ADDED and CARTONS_PULLED?

I also need to timestamp each new, add and pull.

```
 TABLE NAME:  cartons_current
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | Column     |  Type        |  Null  |  Key   |  Default          |  Extra     |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | part_no    | varchar(20)  |  No    |  Prim  |                   |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | qty        | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | qty_time   | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | add_qty    | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | add_time   | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | pull_qty   | int(8)       |  No    |        |                   |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
 | pull_time  | timestamp    |  No    |        | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |            |
 +------------+--------------+--------+--------+-------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

In a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger you can change the values, so you can do your timestamp magic in those, you you store the last change.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER ai_cartons_each BEFORE UPDATE ON cartons 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF new.qty_added <> old.qty_added THEN 
    SET new.added_timestamp = NOW();
  END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

See also this answer to your other question:

[How do I update a qty field from adding and subtracting fields with timestamps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488502/how-do-i-update-a-qty-field-from-adding-and-subtracting-fields-with-timestamps/7488650#7488650)